# MongoDB deleting aggregated cells

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I have a problem.

I have collection of documents like this:

```
{
  id (not _id),
  type,
  number
}
```

And what I want to do is aggregate cells with specific type and minimum number for this type for every id and delete them from this collection. Basically, single id can have few different number for specific type and I want to delete Document with the lowest value.

I tried to aggregate it using Java Driver 3 and mongoshell but I stucked on constructing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from something like this

```
List<DBObject> pipeline=new ArrayList<DBObject>();
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("date", sdf.format(new Date())).append("country", country).append("operator", operator).append("server_ip", server_ip));
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$details");
DBObject match2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("details.type", "application_health"));
DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("details.datetime", -1));
DBObject limit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", 1);
pipeline.add(match);
pipeline.add(unwind);
pipeline.add(match2);
pipeline.add(sort);
pipeline.add(limit);
AggregationOutput outputoutput = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```